# Mocked method isn't called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have test method and it fails on calling mocked method.

The controller I want to test:

```
public class DocumentsController : BaseController
{
    public IDocumentRepository DocumentRepository { get; private set; }

    public DocumentsController(IDocumentRepository documentRepository)
    {
        DocumentRepository = documentRepository;
    }

    public Documents GetDocuments(int projectPK, int? folderPK, string search, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        Documents documents =
            DocumentRepository.GetDocuments(
                projectPK,
                folderPK,
                true,
                search,
                UserPK, //saved in HttpConfiguration
                page,
                pageSize,
                CustomerConnectionString //saved in HttpConfiguration
            );

        return documents;
    }
}
```

The mocked interface:

```
public interface IDocumentRepository
{
    Documents GetDocuments(
        int projectPK,
        int? folderPK,
        bool useFolders,
        string search,
        int user,
        int page, 
        int pageSize,
        string customerConnectionString);
}
```

And this is the setup and call of mocked method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDocuments_ActionExecutes_ReturnsDocuments()
{
    Mock<IDocumentRepository> repositoryMock =
        new Mock<IDocumentRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            repositoryMock        
                .Setup(
                    c => c.GetDocuments(
                            It.IsAny<int>(),
                            It.IsAny<int?>(),
                            It.IsAny<bool>(),
                            It.IsAny<string>(),
                            It.IsAny<int>(),
                            It.IsAny<int>(),
                            It.IsAny<int>(),
                            It.IsAny<string>()
                        )
                )
                .Returns(new Documents());

    documentsController = new DocumentsController(repositoryMock.Object);
    documentsController.InitHttpConfiguration();

    Documents response =
            documentsController.GetDocuments(
                    projectPK: 1,
                    folderPK: 1,
                    search: "",
                    page: 1,
                    pageSize: 10
            );

    // ... Asserts
}
```

After setting strict mode I've found out the source problem is not called.
I get
`Moq.MockException: IDocumentRepository.GetDocuments(0, null, True, null, 0, 1, 3, "") invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.` on the line where the `DocumentRepository.GetDocuments()` is called from the controller.

Does anyone see any mistake I could have made?

Comment: Why are you using `Is.IsAny<int>` etc when calling `documentsController.GetDocuments`? That makes sense on the *mock*, but not on the class under test...

Comment: @JonSkeet If you look at the body of the controller action, the parameters don't matter, they are only passed to the repository call. Or does it make any difference?

Comment: I don't know - but at the very least it's a confusing and non-idiomatic way of testing, IMO. My guess is that the problem *may* be with the nullable value type parameter... but I haven't used moq enough to know. I'd try to isolate it in a simpler complete example with just one parameter to check.

Comment: Something is fishy; I don't see how you could have passed `1` and `3` to `GetDocuments`.  `It.IsAny<T>` ultimately returns `default(T)`, which in this case would be `0`.  You should put a breakpoint on the invocation to `GetDocuments` and step through the unit test, looking for an unexpected call to that method.

Comment: @JonSkeet The nullable is not the problem. I've updated the source and replaced the It mocks with exact values and I get the same exception.

Comment: Everything looks fine. The `Setup` is correct. The `It.IsAny<>` place-holders in the expression tree you pass are correct. What is `InitHttpConfiguration`? The information you give is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The InitHttpConfiguration only mocks the HttpConfiguration so the controller can get the UserPK and CustomerConnectionString properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for leaving answer instead of comment, but I've no enough reputation.
I have tested that in simple console application and it works, so the error must be somewhere else.

Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78948efcc60bdc64df7e

Comment: Yes, it works now. After cleaning & rebuilding the solution the test passes.